# How to set up FAX modem card on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, modem

I found a modem card in a dumpster yesterday. It's a Conexant RD01-D270 also marketed as "Dell / Conexant N11846 Modem Card".

It still works, I've tested this on Linux, but I'd like to use it in my OpenBSD machine, that handles all my routing, firewalling, access-pointing (is that even a word?).

All I have to do, is connect a telephone cable to it.

But how do I talk to it from OpenBSD (to get into AT-command mode), and how do I set things up so I can send faxes (both ASCII and `.ps` or something) and receive them?

Pointing me to a tutorial, etc. would be great.

It seems there's quite a lot of them around, although the technology is clearly past its prime. They're [sold on eBay](http://www.google.de/imgres?safe=off&sa=X&biw=1473&bih=872&tbm=isch&tbnid=Mv6LHom6ma2o9M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.ebay.com/itm/DELL-CONEXANT-RD01-D270-56K-V-92-PCI-MODEM-8W112-08W112-/280980650329&docid=aZZzV8qf_J0twM&itg=1&imgurl=http://i.ebayimg.com/t/DELL-CONEXANT-RD01-D270-56K-V-92-PCI-MODEM-8W112-08W112-/00/s/NDcxWDU4Ng%253D%253D/%2524T2eC16V,!%29UE9s3wCPIsBQZOjZPzS!~~60_35.JPG&w=300&h=241&ei=Y9QbUur0BoGItQbokYCwDg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=12&vpy=229&dur=347&hovh=144&hovw=194&tx=121&ty=63&page=1&tbnh=139&tbnw=190&start=0&ndsp=38&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:82) in large numbers for next to nothing.